# Getting below error while running code in Android Studio

Tags: android

Getting below error while running code in Android Studio. Please help

E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.example.pulkitrathi.maps.MapsActivity$4.onDataChange(MapsActivity.java:193)

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  
Map<String, String> map_new = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

  line 193         image_path = map_new.get("image");

                  latitude = map_new.get("latitude");

                    longitude = map_new.get("longitude");

                    place = map_new.get("place");
```

Comment: Map should be declared before initialising
`Map<String, String> map_new = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String Map) @Vatsalkesarwani like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method

Comment: No @AmitGarg make changes on the 2nd line where you have initialized the map with `dataSnapshot.getValue();`

Comment: @Vatsalkesarwani: Map<String, String> map_new = new HashMap<>();dataSnapshot.getValue(); like this?

Comment: @Vatsalkesarwani Can you please check and help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

`dataSnapshot.getValue()` is returning null - you have to check that `map_new` is not null before trying to call any methods on it.

```
if (map_new != null) {
   image_path = map_new.get("image");
   latitude = map_new.get("latitude");
   longitude = map_new.get("longitude");
   place = map_new.get("place");
}
```

Comment: Now getting below error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at com.example.pulkitrathi.maps.MapsActivity$4.onDataChange(MapsActivity.java:200)                              LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));

Comment: Could you please help

Comment: i think you should read up on what a NullPointerException is, as a_local_nobody is suggesting above in the comments to your question - because this exchange will be endless otherwise.
you need to ensure you don't call methods on a possible null object.

Comment: Null pointer exception explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it#:~:text=A%20null%20pointer%20exception%20is,field%20of%20a%20null%20object.